# Duplicate key error in pymongo in update_one()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Here I am using update_one() by pymongo with upsert=True.

The expected result is it should merge if the entry already exists.
But this command results Duplicate Key Error.
Logically "uniqueId" and "_id" are primary key. But I haven't set anything manually so only _id is.

```
db.alerts.update_one({"uniqueId":doc['uniqueId']},{"$set":doc,"$max":statusDict,"$min":{"_id":newId}},upsert=True)
```

Error:

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: alerts.alerts index: _id_ dup key: { _id: "336" }
```

This is not expected for update_one() right ?

Simplified Example for the case

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()

collection = db.tests.tests
collection.insert_one({"name":"tom","unique":1,"_id":1})
collection.update_one({"unique":1},{"$set":{"name":"jerry"},"$min":{"_id":0}})
```

This produces error _id field

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'
```

Comment: What's with the `str` cast?

Comment: @D.SM it is not required, actually. But anyways, it doesn't have any effect

Comment: If it is not required, take it out. Comparisons take types into account.

Comment: @D.SM thanks. I have taken it out. The error persists

Comment: Okay, next reduce your example so that it includes code inserting the data and performing the update, with the update failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In update_one we can change or add attributes other than the primary key that is by dafault '_id'.

I swapped the uses for _id and uniqueId in my case. And the code worked.

For the simple example just swapping both with do

```
collection.update_one({"_id":1},{"$set":{"name":"jerry"},"$min":{"unique":0}})
```

You will have to semantically change the use both fields. Or you can change the default primary key.